# Automatically generate SiteTree translation in Silverstripe

Tags: php, localization, translation, silverstripe

Is there a way, to (automatically) generate, or "duplicate", the site tree for a translation into another language? *For example via an url command or something like that.*

Best regards,
Benedikt

Comment: You mean feeding the site tree to google translate and showing it in the returned language or something like that?

Comment: No. I want to prepare the whole site structure for translation. Therefore, I got to initialize a counterpart to each of the existing pages, but with another lang flag.

Answer (score 1):

you probably already found a solution by now ... but for future reference, SilverStripe user **drx** has created a batch action for translations as discussed here: http://silverstripe.org/customising-the-cms/show/7318

Answer (score 1):

Tip:

`->createTranslation()` only creates a live-record even if you call this on a stage-object created with:

```
$a = Versioned::get_one_by_stage($this->ClassName, 'Stage', $this->ClassName.".ID = ".$this->ID);
```

To create Stage and Live-Pages you have to:

```
$translation_GB = $this->createTranslation('en_GB');
$translation_GB->doRestoreToStage();
```

Saving is done automatically in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't duplicate the site tree to create a translation. SilverStripe supports multi-lingual sites. You can read up on it here: http://doc.silverstripe.org/sapphire/en/topics/translation

If you're wanting a way to automate this there's no native support but it wouldn't be hard to do. By URL would just be a matter of adding a function to your Page_Controller or, even better, you could write a simple module if it's something you're going to be doing regularly (just look at the googlesitemaps module for an example as it loops through pages as you'd need to). You can get all pages by calling:

```
Versioned::get_by_stage('SiteTree', 'Live', $filter);
```

Then you'd create your translation(s) as you looped through. You could also do this via commandline by using SilverStripe's CMDline utility "sake": http://doc.silverstripe.org/sapphire/en/topics/commandline

Comment: Yes, but the system creates a (related) copy of this page with another lang flag.

Comment: OK - so you're just wanting a way to do this automatically rather than by editing each page? If so - I've added to my answer above.